# Databases from different docker containers cannot be accessed through one pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have 2 microservices with their own databases and want to deploy it in docker containers.
I created docker-compose file with following content for first microservice:

```
version: '3.8'
  services:
    first-micr:
      image: first-micr:latest
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
      depends_on:
        - db
      environment:
        - SERVER_PORT=8081
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db/first-micr
    db:
      image: postgres:alpine
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
        - POSTGRES_DB=first-micr
      ports:
        - "15432:5432"
      volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      restart: unless-stopped
    pgadmin:
      container_name: pgadmin4_container
      image: dpage/pgadmin4:7
      restart: always
      environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
      ports:
        - "5050:80"
      volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

and for the second

```
version: '3.8'
  services:
    second-micr:
      image: second-micr:latest
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8082:8082"
      depends_on:
        - db
      environment:
        - SERVER_PORT=8082
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db/second-micr
    db:
      image: postgres:alpine
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
        - POSTGRES_DB=second-micr
      ports:
        - "15433:5432"
      volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  db-data:
```

I expected I can access both databases in the same pgadmin, but it doesn't see the second-micr. Seems pgadmin can't connect to database outside of its container. How can I access both databases inside one pgadmin?

Comment: @Pino Yes! Thank you